Do we have any staff on Bricks.SE?
So, there's a Winter/Summer bash hat for looking at a Staff's profile page, but my clicking through our user pages has not revealed any staff on Bricks.SE.  I'm sure I just didn't click through enough pages.  Do we have any SE staff participants?

FYI, all of the CMs have profiles on every Stack Exchange site. (It's part of our onboarding.) So you can always find our profile on another SE network site (e.g. Meta Stack Exchange), then find our profile on any other site in the network from there.

There is an API query to find staff but it appears the list of staff members is out of date. One user who I can think of is Catija.
A full list of the Community Management Team can be found here.
